# Best way to get distinct values

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm using Google-Appengine-NDB. And I'm tried to get distinct values from database but it's not working.

```
Now my code is:
  query_set = cls.query().order(cls.ls) # Getting ordered queries.
  set_of_field = set([data.field for data in query_set]) # And using this loop for differ.`
```

But the loop is taking too long time (over 12 sec).
Please help me, how can I speed up, or how to get distinct values from ndb?

Comment: Go back and try `distinct` as per the answer - Are you sure you have the current SDK.  I just tried distinct - `x = models.Product.query(projection=["product_type"],distinct=True)` and it works as advertised.

Comment: Works for me on latest SDK 1.9.28.388.   One note:  It only works if the projection/distinct are given as part of query() and not as part of fetch on the query object.  One Q:  What is the trade-off between having one model with possible dupes and doing above query to distinct values vs maintaining two models one of which always contains only distinct values?

Answer (score 4):

Try the distinct query,
if your field is indexed you can use this:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection

```
query_set = cls.query(projection=["field"], distinct=True)
set_of_field = [data.field for data in query_set]
```

But if you have a huge list you can either do this in a taskqueue and store the results somewhere or just keep a distinct data in another model.

Comment: Yeah already tried this. But there is error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'distinct'`. So now I'm using taskqueue, thanks for answer.