# Efficient query for distinct property values in GAE Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Is it possible to get distinct values of an indexed property using ndb? I need this to be efficient - there will be few distinct values, but very large number of entries. So query time should be proportional to number of distinct values, not the total number of entries.

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523770/best-way-to-get-distinct-values/18524067#18524067 . What you want to use are projection queries, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection .

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. However, it's still not clear to me how efficient projection query is. When used on indexed property, does it only get indexes, or goes through all entries... I'm not sure how to test this.

Comment: An index needs to be built that matches the projection, and then the entities themselves are not retrieved, everything comes from the index.

Comment: @Ognjen, another thing to realize about app engine is that it NEVER lets you do table scans, which is one reason why it can be limiting compared to a SQL database. The datastore only lets you run queries that use index seeks.

Comment: For reference to what @adevine says: "[Datastore] does this efficiently using the zigzag merge join algorithm, which tends to **scale with the size of the result set** much like querying against the indexes described above under Advanced Search. By design, the datastore supports only operations that scale in this fashion. The performance of operations that scale with the size of the entire database will deteriorate as the datastore grows." (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection)